# How to remove duplicate Value on the basis of key coming from server?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a key name "messageId" which is coming from server in which I am getting a unique message ID and with the same ID but with different key name "gcm.notification.messageId".

I am getting push notifications and I am saving both in a table view (notification in local database and messages from web service).

My Problem:

I have to remove the duplicate message if "messageId" and "gcm.notification.messageId" have same ID

How to achieve?

Comment: can you show your code

Comment: check weather your table view contains that id or not. if yes, then dont add, else add.

Comment: Actually i am new to iOS so I am not getting how to do that with a key?

Comment: post your response which comes from server and post your code that how you adding in database!!!

Comment: "gcm.message_id" = "0:1472103890927950%ff108ef3ff108ef3";
    "gcm.notification.ClaimID" = "";
    "gcm.notification.OrigMsg" = "<p>uk1</p>";
    "gcm.notification.Type" = Message;
    "gcm.notification.messageId" = 1472103890490; This is the response which i am getting for push notification

Comment: If you are using any database like Coredata then simply check whether value exist or not. If exist then over write the existing one.

Comment: message = "<p>uk1</p>";
            messageId = 1472103890490;
            msgCreatedDateTime = "2016-08-25T05:44:51.000Z";This is the response which i am getting for push notification

Comment: You should post your code or response in question instead of comment!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes inside your `php` script from where you are getting duplicate message whether you  are using `APN` `GCM` or any other push notification services.

Or just dont add the duplicate value value.

Comment: They are not adding duplicate one is for push notification and one is for message Id

Comment: so your problem is key `gcm.notification.messageId` and `messageId` getting same message id everytime ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to save data from a notification. A notification is by definition not reliable. If you get it, it's nice, if you don't, you still need to find a way to have a good user experience.

From what you've written, I'm assuming you want to save messages from a remote database to your local database. If I'm mistaken, please clarify and I'll edit.

What you could do is :

- If you get a notification, check your database and see if you already have that message. If you don't, fetch it. If you do have it already, then ignore it.
- If  you don't get the notification, you still need to find a way to fetch recent messages, I suggest simply doing it when the user is about to enter his "Inbox" (or whatever it is in your case), and once you have all the (new) messages, compare the ID's before saving them to the database.

That way, you never save whatever information is in the notification ; you only use that information to fetch appropriate and specific data. If you don't have the luxury of knowing what to fetch, you need to ask the server yourself.

A side note : it's a good idea not to do all that ordering / comparing locally. A good idea is to send the server your latest message and ask him to return you whatever came after that.

-Hey server, here is my latest message ID.

-Ok, I'm seeing that ID, here are all the messages with date > the date of your msg.